# WIndows Task Bar is not showing all Icons at once

Tags: window, taskbar

I have windows 10 installed. I open many application at once for my work and I can access then form my task bar. Task is at right side of the screen but it do not show all the icons at once instead it show a scroll bar. I have increased the width of taskbar still it is not showing all icons. Is there any other setting needs to be changed?

Please refer screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: no, you cannot - at least not for the application icons pinned directly to the taskbar. If you add another symbols folder to the task bar, then you can do this, see:

- https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/107167-multiple-columns-vertical-taskbar.html#post1332812
- https://superuser.com/questions/517701/windows-7-side-taskbar-how-to-have-multiple-icon-columns
- https://superuser.com/questions/1361189/multi-column-taskbar-when-its-on-left-right-in-windows

I never used a vertical taskbar before on Windows (maybe you come from Ubuntu Unity desktop?), but I just tried the idea from the first link and it works. Here is a screenshot from my experiment:

[image: Multi-column taskbar folder]

In combination with small taskbar symbols you could achieve a more compact view.

Another option is to deactivate the title (here: "Desktop") and symbol titles for the taskbar folder, then it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kriegaex , running apps are not stacked but this helps a bit.